# How to resize volume on EC2 - CentOS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, volume

I created EMR on AWS and ssh to a name node.
Noticed there was a space issue and increased volume in AWS console from 200GB -> 500GB.
Then rebooted instance and it is showing that there is no change:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      197G  187G  3.1M 100% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
cm_processes     32G     0   32G   0% /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
```

Tried to check partitions and this is what is showing:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  500G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  200G  0 part /
```

Then did `resize2fs` but is showning `nothing to do`:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 52428544 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Size did not change. 
What should I do next?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the console say, is it done resizing the volume?

Comment: Yes, console says 500GB.

Comment: your lsblk output says your disk is 500G but your partition is 200G. You could either expand your xvda1 partition (which is a risky operation on a live primary filesystem) or create a second partition and mount it in the location you need.

Comment: @RaGe - do you have exact procedure step-by-step for these operations? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Snapshot all ebs volumes you care about before doing any resize operations on them.
2. Install growpart
   `sudo yum install cloud-utils-growpart`
3. Resize partion`growpart /dev/xdva 1`
4. Reboot `reboot now`
5. Run `lsblk` and verify that the partition is now the full disk size
6. You may still have to run `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` to expand the filesystem